# Как разбить на кадры видео, данные которого записаны в blob?

Tags: javascript, blob

Представим, что есть некий blob объект, который является видео. Вопрос как можно разбить такой объект на кадры (изображения)? Я посмотрел на сам blob, это просто запись разных символов разделённых косой чертой `/`. Как браузер понимает, где заканчивается один кадр и начинается другой и как это могу понять я? Нужно сделать это на js на клиентской стороне. Кодек vp8 (если это нужно)